# facebook javascript sdk login not working on iOS / best practices for mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to allow a user to login to my webapp via facebook login using the javascript SDK. It works on desktop (safari and chrome), however the pop up fails on both safari and chrome on iOS.

The error is straight forward to chrome where the browser and OS are not supported. This issue has a work around described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843116/facebook-oauth-unsupported-in-chrome-on-ios). It is less clear what the issue is with safari and not seeing the pop up. The login call is called on a button click so I don't believe the browser should block it. I also tried allowing pop ups as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493198/facebook-login-not-open-in-safari-iphone) but that solution did not work nor is it a viable long term solution to force users to change that setting.

How do folks use facebook login in production and expect it to work on mobile? Do you need to use the [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) fb login? It appears that the javascript SDK doesn't work well with mobile browsers and OS's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is common issue among mobile browsers and you will find that it would also be in some android devices.

For precaution it is under best practice to build flow of login manually.
[Go here as your link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

So yes, you will need to go with manual integration. But, it will be full-proof integration without doubts.