# Will Facebook's manual login flow allow a mobile webview to automatically launch Facebook's native app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, mobile-website, facebook-oauth

I've successfully implemented Facebook login with their Javascript SDK but was hoping that when used on mobile, the native Facebook application would launch. Will going through the manual flow [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) allow this behavior? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524732/facebook-manual-login-flow-open-login-dialog-in-app-if-installed) seems to say otherwise but was vague.

I want to avoid using Android and iOS mobile SDKs because my situation is basically an OAuth within an OAuth and it would get messy. Any other approaches people think could work like redirect URIs or other OAuth magic would be really appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Both the JS SDK and the manual flow are web-based, and have to happen inside a browser or a webview component. They do not involve the native Facebook app.

Comment: @misorude Thanks! Do you know of any other possible way to incorporate the native Facebook app into a webview flow?